# I am studying 'C' and I getting confused on Static and Dynamic memory allocation

Tags: c

I am trying to find the difference between static and dynamic memory allocation...

This is **static memory** allocation:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
int a;
printf("Enter the size of array: ");
scanf("%d",&a);
int arr[a];
for(int i=0;i<a;i++){
    arr[i]=i;
}
for(int i=0;i<a;i++){
    printf("%d\n",arr[i]);
}
return 0;
}
```

**Output:**

```
/tmp/aGaOu4PWEU.o
Enter the size of array: 10
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
```

When we compile and run this we have to enter value of 'a' during run time and size of array arr[] is also set during run time, but how is it compile time???

Comment: You are studying C. Better leave C++ out of your question.

Comment: What is static memory allocation? I don't think there's any such thing in C, although there's a bunch of related concepts -- static storage duration, knowing the size of an object at compile-time, and allocation on the stack.

Comment: "static memory allocation" is a non-sequitur if it means compile-time allocation because all memory allocation is done at program load-time, or program run-time, either implicitly or explicitly.

Comment: @PaulHankin: Allocation is reserving memory. For objects with static storage duration, it happens before or as the program starts. The C standard calls dynamically allocated memory “allocated storage,” but it also uses “allocated” in the sense above. “Static memory allocation” is simply allocation of memory for objects of static storage duration.

Answer (score 0):

What you are using here is a variable length array (VLA for short). It is allocated during runtime, but it is allocated on the stack.

I believe you may confuse static allocation and stack allocation. Static allocation is only possible if the compiler knows the object size at compile time.

Answer (score -1):

A static array is located in a continuous segment of memory, sizeof(int) bytes are allocated for each element of the array, respectively, the amount of memory required to accommodate the entire array is a*sizeof(int) bytes according to your code.  This value is limited from above by the platform and the compiler.  If an array is declared statically, that is, in the global scope, in the scope of a namespace, or as a static member of a class, then it is allocated in static memory.  Arrays declared locally are allocated memory on the stack, which has a limited size.  Dynamic arrays are allocated in dynamic memory.  For dynamic arrays, there are only operations for creating and deleting them; to work with such arrays, pointers to their beginning are used.  The size of such an array must be stored separately, sometimes pointers to the null element are used for this.  If a static array is defined as a global variable (i.e., declared outside the body of any function, or with the static modifier), then its size is added to the total size of all uninitialized global variables of the program, the memory for these variables is allocated by the system entirely at the stage  downloads.  Therefore, the sizes of such arrays can no longer be changed, the compiler needs to know them in advance, which means that only constants are allowed as them.

Comment: This answer is not completely wrong, but it is a large run-on paragraph with some misleading and inappropriate things. Re “A static array is located in a continuous segment of memory”: Any array is a contiguously allocated sequence of objects. Re “This value is limited from above by the platform and the compiler”: The meaning of “limited from above” is not clear. Re “in the global scope”: C does not have a global scope. It has file scope and external linkage. Re “the scope of a namespace”: C does not have this kind of namespace; that is C++.

Comment: Re “Arrays declared locally are allocated memory on the stack”: This is not always true, since declarations with `static` or `extern` do not result in an object with automatic storage duration. Re “Dynamic arrays are allocated in dynamic memory”: “Dynamic arrays” is an ambiguous term; C has variable length arrays which may be called dynamic, but they are not necessarily in the “allocated” storage class.

Comment: Re “For dynamic arrays, there are only operations for creating and deleting them”: What? There are operations for accessing the elements of arrays. Re “The size of such an array must be stored separately, sometimes pointers to the null element are used for this”: The size must be managed somehow (which is not necessarily by explicitly storing it separately). Arrays do not have a “null element” in the sense the C standard uses “null,” except possibly for arrays of pointers.

Comment: Re “the memory for these variables is allocated by the system entirely at the stage downloads”: The meaning of “the stage downloads” is not evident.